# Failed to collect page data for Error in productions build

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I have an application that fetches data from MongoDB. It works fine until I try to create a dynamic route using the `generateStaticParams()` function. Then I get the following error during the build process, as in production:

> info Collecting page data .TypeError: fetch failed  Build error
> occurred Error: Failed to collect page data for /product/[productId]
> at J:\react-projecte\share\node_modules\next\dist\build\utils.js:1161:15
> at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {           type: 'Error' }

I use the App Router approach

app/product/[productId]/page.js:

```
export async function generateStaticParams() {
const fetching = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_URL}api/Products`);
const products = await fetching.json();

return products.data?.map((product) => ({
 productId: product._id,
}));
}
```

Comment: Why the `java` tag?